# Program stops working after selected index change second time listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, listbox

i have a problem that i change selected index in listview it works fine when i change first time but when i change second time it says "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."
 the code is this ;

```
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string a = "";

        a = "";
       a = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;

       StreamReader oku = new StreamReader(strPath+"\\"+"Versiyonlar"+"\\"+a);
       string OkunanVeri = oku.ReadToEnd();
       string[] dizi = OkunanVeri.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       foreach (var item in dizi)
       {
           listBox1.Items.Add(item);
       } 
            oku.Close();
```

strpath is way to desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        try
        {
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
        string a = "";

        a = "";
       a = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;

       StreamReader oku = new StreamReader(strPath+"\\"+"Versiyonlar"+"\\"+a);
       string OkunanVeri = oku.ReadToEnd();
       string[] dizi = OkunanVeri.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       foreach (var item in dizi)
       {
           listBox1.Items.Add(item);
       } 
            oku.Close();
        }
        catch 
        {


        }
```

i just fixed it like this